# failed to commit changes to dconf - Electron application breaking when uploading files

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, electron

my application previously was working perfectly fine on an Ubuntu 22 machine. I could click a file input button on the interface, pull up a graphical file selection window, and upload files like normal.

For some reason, I am now faced with this error repeated many times in the terminal that the Electron application is running in:

`(electron:20508): dconf-WARNING **: 13:43:53.683: failed to commit changes to dconf: Unknown or unsupported transport “disabled” for address “disabled:”` 
a

The file selection window opens and allows me to select a file, but after throwing this warning the application simply becomes un-interactive and I need to close out of it.

I'm very lost and have no clue what to do to approach this problem.

If any code snippets would help, I would gladly provide them.

Comment: This is a strange issue. AFAIK, Electron shouldn't have any business with dconf. In case you're not on the latest Electron version, could you try to upgrade? Also, do all other GNOME application work or are you able to observe the same message thrown when starting other applications from the Terminal?

Comment: Opening gedit from the terminal also throws the same warning but the applications seem to work, I have ran "npm install electron@latest"

Comment: If GNOME applications also throw the error, there's something wrong with either your system, your install of GNOME, some configuration file, your install of dconf, or all of the above. This is only insofar related to Electron as the application hangs. Thus, I suggest you report the issue [at Electron's issue tracker](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues).

Comment: Yea I'm not gonna lie, I did absolutely nothing and the issue resolved itself. I appreciate the help but it seems I will just go forth in my own ignorance and not worry about it.